# Margin space UITableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I want to show margin space left and right in UITableView look like images. I used `Xcode 7.3.1` and deployment target is 7.0. Please help me! Thanks very much.

[image: Images]

Comment: Drag and drop a table view, set left and right constraints as you want above.

Comment: you also can set UIview as a background in your tablviewCell and make its 10 -10 px space from right and left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one `UIView` into cell's contentview and than give constraints to it like below ...

[image]

> Note: Don't forget to add background color to cell's contentview to see the effect.

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! Love you!

Comment: Ok, with pleasure!!

Answer (score 1):

Add left and right constraints as shown in pic below. You can change the margin to the value that you need. Dark red (vs dotted red) connectors says the constraints are selected. Click on "Add 2 constraints" to add it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I can't change constraints. Image: http://i.imgur.com/iKd5NzG.png

Comment: Doesnt the UI allow you to select constraints?

Comment: @Bhavin I don't understand, I'm begin learning swift. Please give me an example website to view

Comment: Sorry to bother you

Comment: @Bhavin Can you use Teamviewer to help me? Thanks